# Validator.ts file throwing error saying "Cannot find Promise"

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, typescript, npm

I ma trying to use the validator.ts for validation in my Node JS typescript application. I ran the command,

```
npm install validator.ts --save
```

and installed it. Now when I run gulp to build my application its throwing the below errors in the validator.ts file.

```
[14:58:24] Starting 'npm'...
[14:58:25] Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 1.8.7
[14:58:27] [tsc] > node_modules/validator.ts/Validator.d.ts(20,73): error TS2304
: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[14:58:27] [tsc] > node_modules/validator.ts/Validator.d.ts(34,34): error TS2304
: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[14:58:27] [tsc] > node_modules/validator.ts/Validator.d.ts(43,84): error TS2304
: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[14:58:27] [tsc] > src/main/EdgeNode.ts(59,27): error TS2346: Supplied parameter
s do not match any signature of call target.
[14:58:27] Failed to compile TypeScript: Error: tsc command has exited with code
:2
[14:58:27] Finished 'npm' after 2.4 s
[14:58:27] Finished 'build-scripts' after 5.73 s
[14:58:27] Starting 'test'...
[14:58:27] Starting 'clean-source-tmp'...
[14:58:27] Finished 'clean-source-tmp' after 3.82 ms
[14:58:27] Starting 'coverage-build'...
[14:58:27] Starting 'clean-source-tmp'...
[14:58:27] Finished 'clean-source-tmp' after 3.72 ms
[14:58:27] Starting 'tmp-scripts'...
G:/Projects/Kube2/edge-node-sdk-js/node_modules/validator.ts/Validator.d.ts(20,7
3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[14:58:28] [Typescript] TypeScript error: G:/Projects/Kube2/edge-node-sdk-js/nod
e_modules/validator.ts/Validator.d.ts(20,73): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Pr
omise'.
G:/Projects/Kube2/edge-node-sdk-js/node_modules/validator.ts/Validator.d.ts(34,3
4): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[14:58:28] [Typescript] TypeScript error: G:/Projects/Kube2/edge-node-sdk-js/nod
e_modules/validator.ts/Validator.d.ts(34,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Pr
omise'.
G:/Projects/Kube2/edge-node-sdk-js/node_modules/validator.ts/Validator.d.ts(43,8
4): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[14:58:28] [Typescript] TypeScript error: G:/Projects/Kube2/edge-node-sdk-js/nod
e_modules/validator.ts/Validator.d.ts(43,84): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Pr
omise'.
src\main\EdgeNode.ts(59,27): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any
signature of call target.
[14:58:28] [Typescript] TypeScript error: src\main\EdgeNode.ts(59,27): error TS2
346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
[14:58:28] TypeScript: 4 semantic errors
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please advice.

I saw some  similar questions and attached the below lines to my main class in which I'm validating. But it still doesn't help.

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/class-validator/Validator.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/class-validator/index.d.ts"/>
```

Comment: why the heck is it downvoted

Comment: What is your target version? If you target ES6 does it suddenly start working?

Comment: I'm writing my code in typescript and its transpiled to ES5. I am not using ES6

Comment: Sure, but if you set the tsconfig to use ES6 does it start working? The Promise interface is part of es6 lib .d.ts file. Try it for a moment and revert it later.

Comment: Yes! When I target ES6 that error is gone. But other libraries I use are throwing errors. I cannot be using ES6. What should I do? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't mind if I move this down as an answer, because unfortunately this seems pretty final.

This error is happening because you're attempting to target ES5 and the Promise interface is not defined. It's defined in [the .d.ts file typescript uses for es6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts).

[Validator.ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator.ts) specifically states that is uses ES6 features. You mention in the comments you can't target ES6.

Your options the way I see them:

1. Target ES6. Note, this doesn't mean you are stuck there, see option 4.
2. Don't use Validator.ts
3. Use the es6-shim as suggested on the [Validator.ts npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator.ts)
4. Use a transpiler like babel to go from Typescript > ES6 > ES5.

Comment: Are there any other validators I can use?